# Ethernet centre tap capacitor on transformer

Tags: voltage, capacitor, transformer, ethernet, magnetics

I'm using the [LAN9353](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/00001925A.pdf) IC with this [evaluation board](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/evb-lan9353-rev-a.pdf) as a reference.

On page 5 of the evaluation board manual, the centre tap capacitor on the transformer is 22 nF.

When the value is changed to 100 nF, it works OK, but if it's 22 nF, it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what the exact reason behind this is, and what the exact capacitor value should be?

Comment: Are you using an actual eval board, or your own PCB based on the Eval board schematic?

Comment: Own PCB board based on the Eval board schematic

Comment: Then it is an issue with your board, either schematic or PCB layout issue. Or maybe some component is loose or broken.

Comment: Any idea or hints on the capacitor values?

Comment: It's a generic bypass cap. The exact value does not matter much. If the value matters, you have a large problem somewhere else.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Any idea on what might be the problem? What could the causes of such a problem?

Comment: Bad pcb layout, bad component choice, poor assembly and so on. Hard to be exact when you have not supplied much information at all. What have you done to diagnose the problem? Looked at the node with an oscilloscope? Have you followed the layout suggestions from Microchip? Have you used a mulimeter to beep out the circuit? Always check the obvious - the obvious being anything you can see, touch or measure easily.